# Independent boolean variable for each item in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a custom play/pause button for my audio items which I did like so...

```
<div v-for="(post, p) in post_list">
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <v-avatar v-if="!is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
        @click="playMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)"> <!-- is_played = true -->
            <v-icon dark> mdi-play </v-icon>
     </v-avatar> 

     <v-avatar v-if="is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
        @click="pauseMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)"> <!-- is_played = false-->
            <v-icon dark> mdi-pause </v-icon>
     </v-avatar> 
</div>
```

The above code toggles from pause icon to play icon on click. The problem is that, it affects all play/pause button for all items since the `is_played` is assigned for all the items.

What I want is that `is_played` should only affect one item and should only be exclusive to the item that I toggle play/pause button.

**EDITED: Here's the play/pause function**

```
playMe(c, index) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].play();
        this.is_played = true;
    },
    pauseMe(c, index) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].pause();
        this.is_played = false;
    },
```

Comment: Although you seem to pass a specific reference of the current item to `pauseMe` method (the `p` index), it sounds like you are not making use of it. Since that's where the problem is, if you need help you'll have to share the contents of that function. Also you should probably only pass the index (without the `custom-wave-aud-` prefix) assuming `pauseMe` function only handles play/pause buttons. Even if it does handle multiple types of buttons, it would be cleaner to pass the `index` and the `type` as separate arguments.

Comment: That's the problem: you use the same value `is_played` in each button. When you change it, it will affect all buttons. You probably want to place the index of the audio resource inside `is_played` and change the v-if to `v-if="is_played === p"`. I voted for reopening your question, which is all I can do at this point. @Boussadjra, while your vote is correct, it doesn't help OP as they don't have enough experience to apply the linked question to their case. You might want to consider re-opening.

Comment: @tao I've actually tried it, but no buttons are displayed on initial render since `is_played` is never equal `p`

Comment: Initialize it with `0` in `data`, obviously: `data: () => ({ is_played: 0 })`. Do you have a [mcve]? jsfiddle, codesandbox.io, codepen.... !?

Comment: every item of `post_list` can hold a `is_played` prop, then if playMe is called, you set specific item's `is_played` value to true/false, at the same, render the template use single  item's prop `is_played`, not a `this` prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, you have to reference the `index` of the current post in `is_played`. Otherwise all the buttons will change when `is_played` changes. Here's some sample code which should do that:

```html
<div v-for="(post, p) in post_list" :key="p">
  <v-avatar v-if="is_played !== p"
            color="#663399"
            size="42"
            class="mx-2"
            @click="playMe('custom-wave-aud-' + p, p)">
    <v-icon dark>mdi-play</v-icon>
  </v-avatar>
  <v-avatar v-if="is_played === p"
            color="#663399"
            size="42"
            class="mx-2"
            @click="pauseMe('custom-wave-aud-' + p, p)">
    <v-icon dark>mdi-pause</v-icon>
  </v-avatar>
</div>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  is_played: null
}),
methods: {
  playMe(className, index) {
    if (this.is_played !== null) {
      // pause the currently playing one first
      this.pauseMe(className, this.is_played);
    }
    this.is_played = index;
    document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].play();
  },
  pauseMe(className, index) {
    this.is_played = null;
    document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].pause();
  }
}
```

Note: the above code assumes you don't want more than one of the wavs to play at one time. If you do want to allow playing multiple at the same time, you'll have to change `is_playing` to an array and change the condition to check if current index is contained in the array. Obviously, you'll want to add/remove the index to the array when playing/pausing.

If you need more help, please provide a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).